# Is there a way to test for a null value in this expression within a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, isnull

Is there a way to test for a null value in this expression within a bat file?

```
FOR /F %%f IN ('C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /text:name /bindings:') DO rmdir /s/q "D:\Websites\%%f"
```

Such that it won't execute the Do rmdir statement if %%f is empty?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: `FOR /F` execute the line after `DO` _with every value_ generated by the command in parentheses. If there are not values, then executes no commands

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be necessary. If the output of `APPCMD` is an empty string, `FOR /F` will ignore it (also if the line starts `;`)

Now if any line contains just spaces, that's another issue.

Check by running this batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal
FOR /F %%f IN ('C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /text:name /bindings:') DO ECHO ++%%f$$
pause
```

This will show each item returned, with `++` at the start and `$$` at the end of each line.

If an unwanted name gets reported, then we need to deal with it.

Things to look for:

- ++ at the start and $$ at the end of EACH line
- No lines appear to start $$
- There may be a line "++[spaces]$$"
- There should be no line "++$$"